# How to load Group.Owner properties using CSOM

Tags: client-object-model, permissions, groups, spprincipal

When I try to load

```
owner = TargetSite.Web.EnsureUser(grp.Owner.LoginName);
```

I got the  exception :

> The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been
>        requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be
>        explicitly requested

How can I lod this properties ? 
.

```
  private static void InsertGroup()
    {
        GroupCreationInformation groupCreationInfo = new GroupCreationInformation();
        try
        {  
             foreach(string Item in Selecteditems ){
            foreach (Group grp in SourceGroups)
            {

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(grp.Title) && grp.Title == Item)
                {
                    try
                    {  
                         using(var srcSite =  new ClientContext(grp.Context.Url)){
                        groupCreationInfo.Title = grp.Title;

                        // if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(grp.Description))
                        //  groupCreationInfo.Description = grp.Description;  
                        User owner  = null;
                       // SourceSite.Web.Context.Load(grp.Users);  


                        //clientContext.Load(siteGroup);
                        //clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                        //clientContext.Load(siteGroup.Owner);
                        //clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                        srcSite.Load(grp);
                        srcSite.ExecuteQuery();
                        srcSite.Load(grp.Owner);
                        srcSite.ExecuteQuery();
                        //load the client object list.RootFolder.Folders
                      // Principal p = grp.Owner; 

                        try
                        {
                            owner = TargetSite.Web.EnsureUser(grp.Owner.LoginName);
                        }
                        catch {   /*L'utente non essite */    }
                        // User member = TargetSite.Web.EnsureUser(grp.Owner.LoginName);

                        Group Tgroup = TargetSite.Web.SiteGroups.Add(groupCreationInfo);
                        Tgroup.Owner = owner;
                       // group.Users.AddUser(member);
                        Tgroup.Update();

                        TargetSite.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                    }
                    catch { }


                }

            }
```

I also have the same error in other method, if I include  `group => group.Owner`

into it

```
private static List<Group> GetGroups(ClientContext Context)
        {

            try
            {
                List<Group> gps = new List<Group>();
                Web web = Context.Web;
                GroupCollection groupColl = web.SiteGroups;
                Context.Load(groupColl,
                    groups => groups.Include(
                    group => group.Title,
                    group => group.Id ,
                   group=> group.OwnerTitle,                       
                   // group => group.Owner
                    ));
                Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Where does `grp` come from? if it's from a different ClientContext (and it has to be, since you are not loading the group anywhere in the ClientContext you posted), you will see this error.

Comment: I think it's ok now. But I still have the same error!

Comment: What is `SourceGroups`? These groups are still from a different context. You cannot just load them in your new context.

Comment: ok. But why have I the same error in the other snipet? The second one should be correct.

Comment: That's strange indeed. Try loading the owner with all of these fields `Context.Load(grp.Owner, o => o.Id, o => o.LoginName, o => o.Title, o => o.PrincipalType);`. Maybe this helps. If not, then I am also out if ideas.

Comment: Similar thread is [here][1] see if this can help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653909/how-to-add-a-sharepoint-group-as-group-owner-with-client-object-model

Comment: this is not an actual answer but I don't have enough reputation to comment. AFAIK, this is due to a bug ("feature"?) in the serialization of the group owner. If you want the owner information, you will have to retrieve, as mentioned, the group.OwnerTitle value and then make another request to search within the web.SiteUsers. You can verify this by running your (failing) query and looking a the ULS logs. That symptoms to this are that, if you make the call from within the same machine SP is running, you will get an "Unknown Server Exception" (meaning the response stream was closed by a non seri